# Is "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" necessary?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo

I´m rewritting our database class (PDO based), and got stuck at this. I´ve been taught to both use `SET NAMES utf8` and `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` when working with UTF-8 in PHP and MySQL.

In PDO I now want to use the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` parameter, but it only supports one query.

Is `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` necessary?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Using `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` after using `SET NAMES utf8` will actually reset the `character_set_connection` and `collation_connection` to
`@@character_set_database` and `@@collation_database` respectively.

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) states that

- `SET NAMES x` is equivalent to

  ```
  SET character_set_client = x;
  SET character_set_results = x;
  SET character_set_connection = x;
  ```
- and `SET CHARACTER SET x` is equivalent to

  ```
  SET character_set_client = x;
  SET character_set_results = x;
  SET collation_connection = @@collation_database;
  ```

whereas `SET collation_connection = x` also internally executes `SET character_set_connection = <<character_set_of_collation_x>>` and `SET character_set_connection = x` internally also executes `SET collation_connection = <<default_collation_of_character_set_x`.

So essentially you're resetting `character_set_connection` to `@@character_set_database` and `collation_connection` to `@@collation_database`. The manual explains the usage of these variables:

> *What character set should the server
>   translate a statement to after
>   receiving it?*
>
> For this, the server uses the
>   character_set_connection and
>   collation_connection system variables.
>   It converts statements sent by the
>   client from character_set_client to
>   character_set_connection (except for
>   string literals that have an
>   introducer such as _latin1 or _utf8).
>   collation_connection is important for
>   comparisons of literal strings. For
>   comparisons of strings with column
>   values, collation_connection does not
>   matter because columns have their own
>   collation, which has a higher
>   collation precedence.

To sum this up, the encoding/transcoding procedure MySQL uses to process the query and its results is a multi-step-thing:

1. MySQL treats the incoming query as being encoded in `character_set_client`.
2. MySQL transcodes the statement from `character_set_client` into `character_set_connection`
3. when comparing string values to column values MySQL transcodes the string value from `character_set_connection` into the character set of the given database column and uses the column collation to do sorting and comparison.
4. MySQL builds up the result set encoded in `character_set_results` (this includes result data as well as result metadata such as column names and so on)

So it could be the case that a `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` would not be sufficient to provide full UTF-8 support. Think of a default database character set of `latin1` and columns defined with `utf8`-charset and go through the steps described above. As `latin1` cannot cover all the characters that UTF-8 can cover you may lose character information in step *3*.

- **Step *3*:** Given that your query is encoded in UTF-8 and contains characters that cannot be represented with `latin1`, these characters will be lost on transcoding from `utf8` to `latin1` (the default database character set) making your query fail.

So I think it's safe to say that `SET NAMES ...` is the correct way to handle character set issues. Even though I might add that setting up your MySQL server variables correctly (all the required variables can be set statically in your `my.cnf`) frees you from the performance overhead of the extra query required on every connect.

Comment: Wow, I´m speechless! Thanks! You deserve a gold star :-)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the extensive write-up. I understand how/when the 3 should be used.

Comment: Great, great, great answer!

Comment: I believe you've already partially answered this for step 3 but I'd like to dive a little deeper. For steps 2-4 what if the characters cannot be represented in the destination encoding? Are they excluded or replaced with an unknown char character? Or would the char be misinterpreted as 2-4 latin1 chars (chars that extend ASCII with their MSB set i.e. the degrees ° symbol)?
Obviously the reverse (from latin1 to utf8) would be ok, as utf8mb4 can represented all unicode chars.

Answer (score 2):

From the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html):

> SET CHARACTER SET is similar to SET
>   NAMES but sets
>   `character_set_connection`  and
>   `collation_connection` to
>   `character_set_database` and
>   `collation_database`. A `SET CHARACTER
>   SET x` statement is equivalent to these
>   three statements:
>
> ```
> SET character_set_client = x;
> SET character_set_results = x;
> SET collation_connection = @@collation_database;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since needing to support international characters sets, I've always just set the the character set of the text type fields on database creation.

I've also always used UTF-8.

Within PHP set the same:

```
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
```

Comment: By the way: setting the collations of database columns is not sufficient to provide UTF-8 support. There are a lot more thing going on between your PHP script and the actual database column.

Comment: Thank you.  I've never been bitten by this yet.  Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The answer many people are looking for is if these queries are needed at all.

As stated in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html):

> If you want the client program to communicate with the server using a
> character set different from the default, you'll need to indicate
> which one.

Note that this is an `if` clause. It means these queries are needed **only if** you want to use a charset different from the default your MySQL is using. Doing the same query over and over if not needed like this is a useless waste of resources and should be avoided:

[image]

At the time of writing (MySQL 8.0.29) the default MySQL server character set is `utf8mb4` and there are no plans to change it for the foreseeable future. You should first check what the current values are, if you get results like these, these queries can be safely removed:

```
mysql> select @@character_set_client;
+------------------------+
| @@character_set_client |
+------------------------+
| utf8mb4                |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@character_set_connection;
+----------------------------+
| @@character_set_connection |
+----------------------------+
| utf8mb4                    |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@character_set_results;
+-------------------------+
| @@character_set_results |
+-------------------------+
| utf8mb4                 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@collation_connection;
+------------------------+
| @@collation_connection |
+------------------------+
| utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci     |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@collation_database;
+----------------------+
| @@collation_database |
+----------------------+
| utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci   |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you get different results but you control the MySQL configuration, you should change them in the MySQL config files, unless you have different applications requiring different charset. (But nowadays `utf8mb4` is the standard and there are very few valid reasons to use a different charset)