# C# ODBC Exception Incorrect String value

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, character-encoding

I am using C# to parse a chat log and insert messages into a database.

When trying to insert the string  `"Don't worry, it's unloaded"`
(with the double quotes) it gives me the following exception:

`System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.11]Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBB\xBF it...' for column 'msg' at row 1
   at void System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)`

The database is using latin-1 default collation for the encoding scheme.

I have tried switching to utf-8 but this gave me the error on the same line.

Comment: Can we see the code used to insert the string?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what it means to your specific error, but `EF BB BF` is the UTF [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character which could be causing an issue.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615611/utf-8-database-problem) pointed out that the client connection needs to be set to the proper character set as well. It could be that the C# client character isn't matching the MySQL encoding.

Comment: As @Paul DelRe said, it's the BOM that you're seeing. It's also very important to understand that just because something looks like text in Notepad doesn't mean that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your chosen way to insert data (I assume by building the SQL directly), the `'` character needs to be escaped. That's because `'` is string delimiting character in most databases.

What you need to insert is `"Don''t worry, it''s unloaded"`, with the single quotes escaped by doubling them.

**!Important:** You need to be careful about raw using raw SQL as it can easily create security holes that can [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use parametrized queries whenever possible or fully escape the query sent to the server.

Comment: WARNING: Not only apostrophes need to be escaped if you create the query dynamically, also backslashes need to be escaped. Replace backslashes with double backslashes, then apostropes with a backslash and an apostrophe.

Comment: `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("msg", message.Msg);`

I am using parameter queries. The above is my line that adds the message to the insert query. 
I looked at the actual text and found that there is an obscure character in the sentence. It is unrecognized in my operating system and just shows up as a box. 
Is there a way to easily filter these characters out? or insert them in  their raw form as an unrecognized character?

Answer (score 0):

User SQL Parameters instead of using raw sql. There can be SQL Injection security issue and these sort of issues.

See how to use sql parameters [mysql-c#](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html)

Eg:

```
MySqlCommand mySqlCommand1;
...
mySqlCommand1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname, desc) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("param1", 30);
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("param2", "SALES");
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("param3", @"Don''t worry, it''s unloaded");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that if you're constructing the SQL statement (don't! -- use a parameterized query instead), if the construct winds up looking like:

```
insert foo ( bar ) values( "This is my data" )
```

The insert will fail because the double quote introduces a **quoted column name**. It is not the same as a string literal which is quoted with the apostrophe (`'`).