# Inserting UTF-8 encoded string into UTF-8 encoded mysql table fails with "Incorrect string value"

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Inserting UTF-8 encoded string into UTF-8 encoded table gives incorrect string value.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x84\x8E i...' for column 'body_value' at row 1: INSERT INTO

I have a  character, in a string that [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) claims is UTF-8 encoded.
I try to insert this string into a MySQL table, which is defined as (among other things) `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

**Edit:** Drupal always does `SET NAMES utf8` with optional `COLLATE` (atleast when talking to MySQL).

**Edit 2:** Some more details that appear to be relevant. I grab some text from a PostgreSQL database. I stick it onto an object, use mb_detect_encoding to verify that it's UTF-8, and persist the object to the database, using [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7). So while there is an HTTP request that triggers the import, the data does not come from the browser.

**Edit 3:** Data is denormalized over two tables:

> SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C WHERE table_schema = "[database]" AND table_name IN ("field_data_body", "field_revision_body") AND column_name = "body_value";

```
>+--------------------+
| character_set_name |
+--------------------+
| utf8               |
| utf8               |
+--------------------+
```

**Edit 4:** Is it possible that the character is "to new"? I'm more than a little fuzzy on [the relationship between unicode and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode), but this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Musical_symbols), implies that the character was standardized very recently.

I don't understand how that can fail with "Incorrect string value".

Comment: Is the field on that table defined with a UTF-8 charset?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 Database Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615611/utf-8-database-problem)

Comment: What does `SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.\`COLUMNS\` C
WHERE table_schema = "db_name"
  AND table_name = "table_name"
  AND column_name = "column_name";` give

Comment: MySQL's `utf8` is only the BMP.  Its `utf8mb4` corresponds to the outside world's `UTF-8` (and includes 4-byte characters).

Comment: The error is caused by trying to cram 4 bytes into a charset that can't handle it (namely MySQL's "utf8").

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(U+1D10E) is a character Unicode found outside the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) (above U+FFFF) and thus can't be represented in UTF-8 in 3 bytes. MySQL charset utf8 only accepts UTF-8 characters if they can be represented in 3 bytes. If you need to store this in MySQL, you'll need to use MySQL charset utf8mb4. You'll need MySQL 5.5.3 or later. You can use ALTER TABLE to change the character set without much problem; since it needs more space to store the characters, a couple issues show up that may require you to reduce string size. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-upgrading.html .

Comment: Great, thank you so much. ALTERing the table, and doing "SET NAMES" when doing this particular type of save, solved the problem for me.

Comment: Is there solutions for older versions of MySQL?

Comment: If he can change databases, surely he can upgrade MySQL a lot easier then using Postgresql.

Comment: @JeromeJ - 5.5.3 is when utf8mb4 was introduced.  Sorry, there is no _text_ way to store 4-byte UTF-8 (non-BMP) characters.

Comment: @RickJames I think I did end up replacing all 4-byte UTF-8 by their HTML character before saving the string.

Answer (score 8):

to solve this issue, first you change your database field to utf8m4b charset. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `tb_name` CHANGE `field_name` `field_name` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

then in your db connection, set driver_options for it to utf8mb4. For example, if you use PDO

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password');
```

or in zend framework 1.2

```
$dbParam = array('host' => 'localhost', 'username' => 'db_user_name',
            'password' => 'password', 'dbname' => 'db_name',
            'driver_options' => array(
                '1002' => "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'",
                '12'    => 0 //this is not necessary
            )
        );
```

Comment: What do 1002 and 12 represent here?

Comment: They are options of driver_options in PDO mysql. You can refer here for more detail https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND (1002) and PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR (12).  Is FETCH_KEY_PAIR necessary here in relation to the question?

Answer (score 4):

In your PDO connecton, set the charset.

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=the_db;charset=utf8mb4', $user, $password);
```

Comment: Does my edit to the question about 'SET NAMES' change this? I can't imagine a framework as well used would get that wrong.

Comment: That's odd, what/where are you inserting?  Might try adding utf8 in the header:
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: My `<HEAD>` contains `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`, but no data comes from the browser. (I updated the question with more data, again)

Comment: No.  It must be `utf8mb4`, not just `utf8`.  (I edited the answer.)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value ......
with this method:

I use utf8mb4_unicode_ci for database
[image: database]
Set utf8mb4_unicode_ci for all tables
[image: tables]

**Set longblog datatype for column** (not text, longtext.... you need big datatype to store 4 bytes of your content)
[image: fields]

It is okay now.
If you use laravel, continue to edit config/database.php

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

[image: laravel]

If you use function strtolower, replace it with mb_strtolower
Notice: you have to put `<meta charset="utf-8">` on your head tag