# UTF 8 - Error 1366 (HY000) - Incorrect string value on data insertion

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

**Utf8** **collated with** my native language collation **"utf_slovak_ci"** **does not allow me to insert** words with special characters like "ľ,š,š,č,ť,ž,ý,á,í,é,ô,ň,ä" which are specific for my language.

The whole situation is pictured here:

[image]

Where could be the problem? Should I switch the charsets? If yes, then which one to use? Or is it any other problem I do not see?

I read quite a lot of Q&A on this topic but none seem to answer my question. The only thing I became aware of is the possibility, that there might be an issue with "cmd.exe" on this. But switching to **"cp850"** or **"cp1250"** did not help either.

Comment: Could this be possibly of a help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936950/inserting-utf-8-encoded-string-into-utf-8-encoded-mysql-table-fails-with-incorr

Comment: @TomasMatejicek - Thanks for the hint - but I have been through that question already and I did not find it useful. THe problem is that SET NAMES or ALTER TABLE do not solve the problem in my case (tried out already).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500

Comment: @KarolS - Thank you! Your suggestion helped me to solve the problem.

The magic is the following: 

set chcp1250 in cmd
SET NAMES  cp1250 in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the charset of your written sql...

1. Write your SQL in a file. **But think about it, to save the file as UTF-8 encoded.**
2. After that import your sql from the file by using the following command

`mysql -u [USERNAME] -p [DATABASENAME] < /[DIRECTORY]/SQLFILE.sql`

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works in mysql shell, try to change some settings in mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

Answer finally found for me in [MySQL utf8mb4, Errors when saving Emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis)