# How to read Chinese text from a database using DBI?

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a database with a list of articles in Chinese and I'm having a problem when I try to do my query to get all the articles names, all I see is ??? and not the Chinese text.

```
my $db_connection = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:host=localhost;database=articles", 'root', ''); 
my $con  = $db_connection->prepare( "select * from articles" );

$con->execute;

while (my $infoD = $con->fetchrow_hashref())
{
    $INFO{$infoD->{name}} .=   decode('utf8', $infoD->{name});  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

declare in your connection string also that it should use utf8

```
DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:host=localhost;database=articles", 'root', '',{mysql_enable_utf8 => 1});
```

If you have utf8mb4

you have to replace `{mysql_enable_utf8 => 1}`  with `{mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1}`

Edit:

also see here [UTF8 all the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095860/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-utf8-within-a-perl-script)