# Hibernate MYSQL character exception

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to save twitter data from twitter API  in my mysql database. But some user's tweets different character.

> Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x87\xB5\xF0\x9F...' for column
>   'name' at row 1 HHH000346: Error during managed flush
>   [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute
>   statement]

my connection url is :

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/social_media?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

And i changed mysql variables and tables charecter encodings. When i run below query

```
> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR
> Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

result is :

```
character_set_client     : utf8mb4 
character_set_connection : utf8mb4 
character_set_database   : utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem : binary  
character_set_results    : utf8mb4 
character_set_server     : utf8mb4
character_set_system     : utf8
collation_connection     : utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database       : utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server         : utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in your environment is not set up to correctly process Unicode text.

The byte sequence `F0 9F 98 9C`, represented incorrectly as "ðŸ˜œ" in your query, is the UTF8 encoding of the Unicode character "", FACE WITH STUCK-OUT TONGUE AND WINKING EYE. (That is, it's an emoji character.)

To store this character correctly, you will need to make sure that:

- You are enabling UTF8 on your MySQL connection (i.e, `SET NAMES utf8mb4`, or use an option when connecting that similarly enables it).
- You are running MySQL 5.5 or later.
- Your table's character set is `utf8mb4`.

taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34165651/6572971

Comment: i did all of them