# How to parse Special Characters with PHP into MySQL?

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, special-characters

I'm parsing some data by using PHP and putting it into MySQL. But if the data contains Special Characters like `êm-Khê` MySQL is outputting following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xEAm-Kh\xEA...'
```

After i test, MySQL is not the problem. (Table and Column Collation is `utf8_general_ci`) When i INSERT that `êm-Khê` Strings into the Table DIRECTLY (manually), it goes into it. So MySQL can accept that data.

So any idea why it is having this error at PHP level?

I do not understand and having about encoding knowledge very well.

- Why is it `ê` transformed into `\xEA` in the query?

So when i get the data like `ê`, how can i put it into the Database as it is `ê` unchanged?

Comment: Can you post the code that is doing the DB insert

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that your db connection is not UTF8 but probably LATIN1 so you have to either use PHP's function `utf8_encode()` or execute `SET NAMES utf8` after you connect to the database.

```
$handle = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname",
'username', 'password',
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615611/utf-8-database-problem) has some good references and explanations

Comment: PDO? Sorry i am not getting what do you mean. I am using `mysql_connect`. It is not like that.

Comment: Oh, OK i got it by using php `utf8_encode()` method. Thanks x)

Comment: It's good to mention that after 5.3.6 you should use `;charset=utf8` as part of the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's an encoding mismatch between PHP and MySQL. `ê` is not really "transformed" into `\xEA`, it's just that MySQL does not know what the byte sequence `EA` is supposed to be and therefore just complains about the raw bytes being wrong. You need to first know what encoding the strings are in in PHP; which depends on where they are coming from. Then you need to set the correct MySQL connection encoding, so MySQL knows what encoding the strings you're sending it are in. How to do that depends on how exactly you connect to the database.

See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for a rundown of the whole process.

Comment: Hi, the source encoding of string in Php is `utf-8` and it is coming from XML. I mean, the XML is encoded as `utf-8`.

Comment: Then double check that using `bin2hex` on the query you are sending to the database, and check what your connection encoding is set to.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this function.
mysql_real_escape_string($user),
 mysql_real_escape_string($password));