# Set character set using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm fetching data in Arabic from MySQL tables with MySQLi. So I usually use this in procedural style:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Now I am using the OOP style so I am trying to see if there is something I could set rather than the above?

I only found this in PHP manual so I did it, but what about setting names to UTF8?

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: Note that `mysqli_set_charset` exists in the procedural style too - there are no differences in the actual capabilities or behaviour of the procedural and OOP styles for using MySQLi. Also note that using `SET NAMES` or `SET CHARACTER SET` explicitly here would be wrong in either style; always prefer `mysqli_set_charset` (or its OOP equivalent).

Comment: Do _not_ mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` interfaces.  Simply do _not_ use the deprecated (and removed in PHP 5.7) `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<del>It's the same:</del>

<del>$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");</del>

***From the manual:***

> This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysqli::query()
>   to execute SET NAMES .. is not recommended.

`$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` is just enough, let the mysqli db driver do the thing for you.

Comment: So do I keep what I found in PHP manual + what you have here, or one would suffice?

Comment: The documentation says `...Using mysqli::query() to execute SET NAMES .. is not recommended.` http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: @sys_debug It looks like you don't need to do `SET NAMES 'utf8'`, `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` will be enough.

Comment: This is confusing. You're saying to use `SET NAMES`, then immediately saying *not* to use `SET NAMES`.

Answer (score 16):

You should use

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

*Don't* use `SET NAMES` or `SET CHARACTER SET` explicitly when using MySQLi., and certainly don't use both like the question asker here originally was. Reasons that this is a bad idea:

- Calling `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`  after `SET NAMES utf8` actually just [*undoes* some of the work that `SET NAMES` did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566908/1709587).
- The PHP manual [explicitly warns us](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php#refsect1-mysqli.set-charset-notes) to use `mysqli_set_charset`, not `SET NAMES`:

  > This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysqli_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended. See the MySQL character set concepts section for more information.
- Under the hood, `mysqli_set_charset` is [just a wrapper for `mysql_set_character_set`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.0.6/ext/mysqli/mysqli_nonapi.c#L956) from the MySQL C API (or its mysqlnd equivalent). Looking at the [docs for that function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-set-character-set.html), we can see the difference between it and `SET NAMES`:

  > This function works like the `SET NAMES` statement, but also sets the value of `mysql->charset`, and thus affects the character set used by `mysql_real_escape_string()`

  In other words, `$mysqli->set_charset('foo')` will do everything `SET NAMES foo` does and *also* ensure that `mysqli_real_escape_string` respects the new encoding. Admittedly, if you're only using encodings like Latin 1 and UTF 8 that strictly extend ASCII (that is, which encode all ASCII strings exactly as they would be encoded in ASCII), then using `SET NAMES` instead of `set_charset` won't break anything. However, if you're using more unusual encodings like GBK, then you could end up garbling your strings or even introducing [SQL injection vulnerabilities that bypass `mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/1709587).

It's thus good practice to only use `set_charset`, not `SET NAMES`. There's nothing that `SET NAMES` does that `set_charset` doesn't, and `set_charset` avoids the risk of `mysqli_real_escape_string` behaving incorrectly (or even insecurely).

Answer (score 14):

For procedural style lovers.

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

/* change character set to utf8 */
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

Comment: Please don't use die() to report errors. See [Error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)

Answer (score 13):

You can use this. Its realy nice for mysqli Character Set

```
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "dbpass";
$dbname     = "dbname";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
mysqli_query($conn,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($conn,"SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'latin5'");
```

$conn = connection string

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.