# PHP: problems outputting utf8 from MySQL database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, pdo

```
$dbo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "databaseuser",
  "databasepassword", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$dbo -> exec("set character_set_client='utf8'");
$dbo -> exec("set character_set_results='utf8'");
$dbo -> exec("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
$prepSnapRetrieve = $dbo->prepare(
  "SELECT * FROM znc_log WHERE `nick` LIKE :u AND `tstamp` BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2"
);
$prepSnapRetrieve->execute(array(':u' => str_replace("|osu","", $_GET['u']),
  ':t1' => $_GET['sns'], ':t2' => $_GET['sne']));
$snapshotListing = $prepSnapRetrieve->fetchAll();
echo("Snapshot of ".$_GET['u']. "'s chat on ".strftime("%e/%m/%g",$_GET['sne']));
echo("<br><br>");
foreach($snapshotListing as $chat) {
  echo "<i>" . " " . "[" . strftime("%H:%M:%S", $chat['tstamp']) . "]" .
   "</i> " . " ><u>" . $chat['channel'] . "</u>< " . "(<b>" .
   htmlspecialchars($chat['nick'])."</b>) ".htmlspecialchars($chat['message']);
  echo("<br>");
}
```

This snippet is code is supposed to parse and output IRC data which has been stored in UTF-8 - but upon echoing, any unicode content simply appears as:

```
??????
```

I have reviewed several questions and included several purported fixes, but nothing appears to work. Another script using the same database echoes UTF-8 content perfectly, but it is using the standard MySQL implementation of PHP, and not PDO. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a client-side issue? Is Content-Type header correct?

Comment: The general troubleshoot guide: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Besides the hint from kgb take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566602/is-set-character-set-utf8-necessary. Might be a good start of ... Your UTF8 settings might get reset in your PDO/exec calls

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple points of failure, when working with UTF8:

- make sure the table is utf8

  Use SQL-Command `Show Variables;` to check the MySQL character settings for the table.
- inserted data is utf8

  You might try tools like **phpMyAdminer** or **Adminer** to check, if the
  data is inserted correctly. Try to insert data via the tool manually.
  When inserting via script, do not use basic string functions. Always use their mbstring
  alternatives. Set `mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );` to let PHP handle UTF-8 internally.
- fetched data is utf8

  I would only use `$pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");` and drop the rest. Because
  `SET NAMES x` is equivalent to
  `SET character_set_client = x;
  SET character_set_results = x;
  SET character_set_connection = x;`
- displayed data is utf8

  If this is displayed in an html page, do not forget to set the meta tag or header
  `"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"`.

Comment: table collation is utf8, data inserted into it is utf8, the fetched data is utf8 and the page it is shown on has both a utf-8 header and a utf8 html meta tag, still no luck

Comment: scratch that, client was not submitting utf8 data properly

Comment: Thank you for `$pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");`. It solves my problem