# json_encode return null even with "SET NAMES utf8" solution

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, json

I get null results after I do a ajax call, where the values have umlauts. I tried to fix this  with:

```
$this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db','user','password',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

The call hierarchy is that the ajax call goes to a php script search.php which have stored a dbconnection object and this is where the sql-calls are going on. I also tried to fix it with utf8_encode but it had no effect. The database is in charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8), too and the php version is 5.4.

In my local apache I dont get any problems. The problem apears only on the real webpage.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the umlauts to HTML entities by using `htmlentities()`, then `json_encode()`.

Comment: didnt helped me. I used htmlentities($products); echo json_encode($products); and also $products = htmlentities($products); but both didnt worked

Comment: ok, then its the database connection or encoding, which is not UTF-8. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11413251/1163786