# Mysql character_set_* variables differ depending on the linux user who logs in

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

Once upon a time, I did this, as the deploy user:

```
alter database crit character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
```

..and then this, again as the deploy user:

```
alter database crit character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci;
```

And now, I get different settings depending on *who* I log into mysql as. First, as the deploy user:

```
deploy@crit$ !mysql
mysql crit -u root -p*** -h ***
...
Server version: 5.6.23-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
...

mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                      |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                      |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.23.R1/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

This is what root's settings look like:

```
root@crit# !mysql
mysql crit -u root -p*** -h ***
...
Server version: 5.6.23-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
...

mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                                    |
| character_set_connection | latin1                                    |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | latin1                                    |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.23.R1/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Why are `character_set_client`, `character_set_connection`, `character_set_results` settings different?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19975025

Comment: Are you using some flavor of "authentication plugin"?

Comment: Do you have `init-connect = SET NAMES utf8` in my.cnf?  `root` ignores it.