# PDO DELETE unexpectedly slow when working with millions of rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working with a MYISAM table that has about 12 million rows. A method is used to delete all records older than a specified date. The table is indexed on the date field. When run in-code, the log shows that this takes about 13 seconds when there are no records to delete and about 25 seconds when there are 1 day's records. When the same query is run in mysql client (taking the query from the SHOW PROCESSLIST when the code is running) it takes no time at all for no records, and about 16 seconds for a day's records.

The real-life problem is that this is taking a long time when there are records to delete when run once a day, so running it more often seems logical. But I'd like it to exit as quick as possible when there is nothing to do.

Method extract:

```
    try {
        $smt = DB::getInstance()->getDbh()->prepare("DELETE FROM " . static::$table . " WHERE dateSent < :date");
        $smt->execute(array(':date' => $date));
        return true;
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        // Some logging here removed to ensure a clean test
    }
```

Log results when 0 rows for deletion:

```
    [debug] ScriptController::actionDeleteHistory() success in 12.82 seconds
```

mysql client when 0 rows for deletion:

```
    mysql> DELETE FROM user_history WHERE dateSent < '2013-05-03 13:41:55';
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Log results when 1 days results for deletion:

```
    [debug] ScriptController::actionDeleteHistory() success in 25.48 seconds
```

mysql client when 1 days results for deletion:

```
    mysql> DELETE FROM user_history WHERE dateSent < '2013-05-05 13:41:55';
    Query OK, 672260 rows affected (15.70 sec)
```

Is there a reason why PDO is slower?

Cheers.

Responses to comments:

It's the same query on both, so the index is either being picked up or it's not. And it is.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM user_history WHERE dateSent < '2013-05-05 13:41:55' 
1   SIMPLE  user_history range  date_sent   date_sent   4   NULL    4   Using where
```

MySQL and Apache are running on the same server for the purposes of this test. If you're getting at an issue of load, then mysql does hit 100% for the 13 seconds on the in-code query. On the mysql client query, it doesn't get chance to register on top before the query is complete. I can't see how this is not something that PHP/PDO is adding to the equation but I'm open to all ideas.

:date is a PDO placeholder, and the fieldname is dateSent so there is no conflict with mysql keywords. Still, using :dateSent instead still causes the delay.

Also already tried without using placeholders but neglected to mention this so good call, thanks! Along the lines of this. Still the same delay with PHP/PDO.

```
DB::getInstance()->getDbh()->query(DELETE FROM user_history WHERE dateSent < '2013-05-03 13:41:55')
```

And using placeholders in mysql client still shows no delay:

```
PREPARE test from 'DELETE FROM user_history WHERE dateSent < ?';
SET @datesent='2013-05-05 13:41:55';
EXECUTE test USING @datesent;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

It's a MYISAM table so no transactions involved on this one.

Value of $date differs to test for no deletions or one day's deletions, as shown in the query run on mysql client which is taken from SHOW PROCESSLIST while the code is running. In this case it is not passed to the method and is derived from:

```
    if (!isset($date)) {
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(sprintf("-%d days", self::DELETE_BEFORE)));
    }
```

And at this point the table schema may get called into question, so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_history` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asin` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dateSent` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`asin`),
  KEY `date_sent` (`dateSent`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

It's a decent sized website with lots of DB calls throughout. I see no evidence in the way the site performs in any other respect that suggests it is down to dodgy routing. Especially as I see this query on SHOW PROCESSLIST slowly creeping its way up to 13 seconds when run in PHP/PDO, but it takes no time at all when run in mysql (particularly referring to where no records are to be deleted which takes 13 seconds in PHP/PDO only).

Currently it is only this particular DELETE query that is in question. But I don't have another bulk DELETE statement like this anywhere else in this project, or any other project of mine that I can think of. So the question is particular to PDO DELETE queries on big-ish tables.

"Isn't that your answer then?" - No. The question is why does this take significantly longer in PHP/PDO compared to mysql client. The SHOW PROCESSLIST only shows this query taking time in PHP/PDO (for no records to be deleted). It takes no time at all in mysql client. That's the point.

Tried the PDO query without the try-catch block, and there is still a delay.

---

And trying with mysql_* functions shows the same timings as with using the mysql client directly. So the finger is pointing quite strongly at PDO right now. It could be my code that interfaces with PDO, but as no other queries have an unexpected delay, this seems less likely:

Method:

```
    $conn = mysql_connect(****);
    mysql_select_db(****);

    $query = "DELETE FROM " . static::$table . " WHERE dateSent < '$date'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Logs for no records to be deleted:

```
Fri May 17 15:12:54 [verbose] UserHistory::deleteBefore() query: DELETE FROM user_history WHERE dateSent < '2013-05-03 15:12:54'
Fri May 17 15:12:54 [verbose] UserHistory::deleteBefore() result: 1
Fri May 17 15:12:54 [verbose] ScriptController::actionDeleteHistory() success in 0.01 seconds
```

Logs for one day's records to be deleted:

```
Fri May 17 15:14:24 [verbose] UserHistory::deleteBefore() query: DELETE FROM user_history WHERE dateSent < '2013-05-07 15:14:08'
Fri May 17 15:14:24 [verbose] UserHistory::deleteBefore() result: 1
Fri May 17 15:14:24 [debug] ScriptController::apiReturn(): {"message":true}
Fri May 17 15:14:24 [verbose] ScriptController::actionDeleteHistory() success in 15.55 seconds
```

---

And tried again avoid calls to DB singleton by creating a PDO connection in the method and using that, and this has a delay once again. Though there are no other delays with other queries that all use the same DB singleton so worth a try, but didn't really expect any difference:

```
    $connectString = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', '****', '****');
    $dbh = new \PDO($connectString, '****', '****');
    $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $smt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM " . static::$table . " WHERE dateSent < :date");
    $smt->execute(array(':date' => $date));
```

---

Calling method with time logger:

```
    $startTimer = microtime(true);
    $deleted = $this->apiReturn(array('message' => UserHistory::deleteBefore()));
    $timeEnd = microtime(true) - $startTimer;
    Logger::write(LOG_VERBOSE, "ScriptController::actionDeleteHistory() success in " . number_format($timeEnd, 2) . " seconds");
```

---

Added PDO/ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to DB::connect(). Still has the delay when deleting no records at all. I've not used this before but it looks like the right format:

```
   $this->dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

---

Current DB::connect(), though if there were general issues with this, surely it would affect all queries?

```
public function connect($host, $user, $pass, $name)
{
    $connectString = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $host, $name);
    $this->dbh = new \PDO($connectString, $user, $pass);
    $this->dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $this->dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 }
```

---

The indexes are shown above in the schema. If it was directly related to rebuilding the indexes after the deletion of the record, then mysql would take the same time as PHP/PDO. It doesn't. This is the issue. It's not that this query is slow - it's expected to take some time. It's that PHP/PDO is noticeably slower than queries executed in the mysql client or  queries that use the mysql lib in PHP.

---

MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY tried, but still a delay

---

DB is a standard singleton pattern. DB::getInstance()->getDbh() returns the PDO connection object created in the DB::connect() method shown above, eg: DB::dbh. I believe I've proved that the DB singleton is not an issue as there is still a delay when creating the PDO connection in the same method as the query is executed (6 edits above).

---

I've found what it causing, but I don't know why this is happening right this minute.

I've created a test SQL that creates a table with 10 million random rows in the right format, and a PHP script that runs the offending query. And it takes no time at all in PHP/PDO or mysql client. Then I change the DB collation from the default latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_unicode_ci and it takes 10 seconds in PHP/PDO and no time at all in mysql client. Then I change it back to latin1_swedish_ci and it takes no time at all in PHP/PDO again.

Tada!

Now if I remove this from the DB connection, it works fine in either collation. So there is some sort of problem here:

```
 $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

I shall research more, then follow up later.

Comment: Did you `EXPLAIN` your query to see if your index is being picked up?

Comment: Are MySQL and your app running on the same machine?

Comment: @markdwhite - Just a thought. Maybe :date is messing things up in the prepare-statement (because date() is a function in mysql). I would try with another variable just to check that it's not that messing it up.

Comment: I'd suggest to try 2 tests: to run from PDO without prepared statements and to run from console with [prepared statements from console](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) "to [see if it's reproduceable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234152/285587)"

Comment: +1 for giving relevant facts and background for the question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - +1. I didn't even know that you could test prepared statements directly in the mysql.

Comment: Wild guess: Are you in a transaction, so it needs to be able to rollback perhaps?

Comment: I guess the backslash is a typo in your catch-block? It might not be the actual pdo-query but something going on with the php-method? May we see the whole method and some function call to it? If you create new php-file with just the call to query. Is it still the same issue?

Comment: The backslah is a namespace specifier, says its defined on the root namespace

Comment: @Orangepill - ok thanks for clearing that up for me! :-)

Comment: What is the value of $date?

Comment: Is it the only query you run from code? There are many question with slowness caused by DNS lookup, solved by changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 (or whatever IP respectively)

Comment: Is it just DELETE-queries that are much slower? (is speed "ok" for select-queries?)

Comment: " Especially as I see this query on SHOW PROCESSLIST slowly creeping its way up to 13 seconds"... ...Isn't that your answer then? ("Value of $date differs to test for no deletions or one day's deletions, as shown in the query run on mysql client which is taken from SHOW PROCESSLIST while the code is running.")

Comment: Ok, can you try another API? mysql, mysqli by chance? In fact, PDO doesn't issue any database commands on it's own - it just translates your SQL to DBMS, that's all. So, it's very unlikely that the problem caused by PDO, not by some silly mistake or measurement error

Comment: Just for the sake of it... Have you tried executing the query without try/catch-block?

Comment: does the table contains VARCHAR or VARBINARY or BLOB columns?

Comment: @AkramBerkawy - yes it contain's varchar (the db-schema is supplied in the question)

Comment: Have you set the PDO-attribute to setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false); ? (The default is true) Or I'll ask instead: What attributes are set for the PDO you are using?

Comment: How does your code for the DB-interface look like?

Comment: How many indexes does you table have?  And how complex are they?  When you delete a row from a table, all indexes need to be rebuilt - which in a case of a very large table can take a very long time.  I had to deal with a table with 100 million records in it with about 50 colunmns and around 10 indexes.  It could take up to 5 minutes to delete one record.

Comment: I rephrase my quesiton: What's the code for the class DB? (What is called when this is done (DB::getInstance()->getDbh()) ?

Comment: Another one. If you play with `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);` would it make any difference?

Comment: A long shot: Maybe the namespace is causing any problem? Next thing I would try is to create a new function connectMySQLI() with settings for the mysqli-interface (with same functionality as your current connect()) and see if there are any difference. (and call connectMysqli() instead of connect() at relevant places in your code)

Comment: The charsets? Ok. Strange but interesting :-)

Comment: It should be $this->dbh->exec("SET NAMES utf8"); and not $this->dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

Comment: Out of interest try the same using mysqli prepare I know PDO is full of overhead but usually its not "that" noticable.  Also have you looked at your mysql config has it got enough cache/prefetch/paging etc for handling a 12 million row table without doing full table searches etc is there enough memory available for its index?

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue with console as well (by sending SET NAMES and stuff)?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - indeed it is. I found that just before I needed to go out earlier.

Comment: @Your Common Sense - indeed I can. See final answer

Answer (score 4):

So...

This post explains where the flaw was.

[Is "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566602/is-set-character-set-utf8-necessary)

Essentially, it was the use of:

```
$this->dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

which should have been this in DB::connect()

```
$this->dbh->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
```

My fault entirely.

It seems to have had dire effects because of a need on the part of the mysql server to convert the query to match the collation of the DB. The above post gives much better details than I can.

If anyone has the need to confirm my findings, this series of SQL queries will setup a test DB and allow you to check for yourself. Just make sure that the indexes are correctly enabled after the test data has been entered because I had to drop and re-add these for some reason. It creates 10 million rows. Maybe less will be enough to prove the point.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS pdo_test;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS pdo_test;
USE pdo_test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asin` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dateSent` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`asin`),
  KEY `date_sent` (`dateSent`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

drop procedure if exists load_test_data;

delimiter #
create procedure load_test_data()
    begin
        declare v_max int unsigned default 10000000;
        declare v_counter int unsigned default 0;

        while v_counter < v_max do
            INSERT INTO test (userId, asin, dateSent) VALUES (FLOOR(1 + RAND()*10000000), SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10), NOW());
            set v_counter=v_counter+1;
        end while;
    end #
delimiter ;

ALTER TABLE test DISABLE KEYS;
call load_test_data();
ALTER TABLE test ENABLE KEYS;

# Tests - reconnect to mysql client after each one to reset previous CHARACTER SET

# Right collation, wrong charset - slow
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER DATABASE pdo_test COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci';
DELETE FROM test  WHERE dateSent < '2013-01-01 00:00:00';

# Wrong collation, no charset - fast
ALTER DATABASE pdo_test COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci';
DELETE FROM test  WHERE dateSent < '2013-01-01 00:00:00';

# Right collation, right charset - fast
SET NAMES utf8;
ALTER DATABASE pdo_test COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci';
DELETE FROM test  WHERE dateSent < '2013-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: What about using explicit dates? `STR_TO_DATE(:dateSent, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')`

Comment: @Sebas In what context? In the original query, or in this SQL to build the test table? If it's for this SQL, it's just one-use throwaway test code. Otherwise, I'm not sure what benefit this will give me in the original query.

Comment: @Sebas Again, in what context and what benefit would it bring? If it's  to compare UNIX_TIMESTAMP then I would just make $date = strtotime("-%d DAYS...etc...) and pass that in as :date. But is this a big time saver on the query?

Comment: I suppose that you would not have the collation problem by comparing dates

Comment: @Sebas I'm not following you. The STR_TO_DATE() function is new to me, and I don't currently see the benefits of using it. But I shall investigate further, thanks.

Comment: When using a litteral date in mysql ('15-01-2001') you're using the internal conversion engine. The column type is DATE, not VARCHAR. Understand? So, using the STR_TO_DATE on your string litteral, you skip the internal process of collation convertion that is apparently the source of your problem.

Comment: @Sebas. Yes - got it now. Pretty obvious now you explain it, but I have missed this in more than a few queries so some refactoring is in order. Thanks for having patience and explaining.

Comment: Finally, this clarifies that, generally, it is safe to use string literals with TIMESTAMP fields as mySQL will perform an internal conversion. There are a few caveats that are worth being aware of where the TIMESTAMP value will be converted to a string for comparison which I assume renders the index useless and would force a full table scan. So refactoring might not be required after all, but this might be a point for investigation if there is problem query showing in mysql logs or STATUS. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-date.html

Answer (score -2):

Try to Analyze and Optimize tables:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: I didn't down vote. I'll leave others to do that if they think it appropriate.

However, I did optimize as part of earlier testing and it made no difference. Current evidence strongly suggests that it's an issue with how I've set the charset for the DB connection.