# my sql dont return value having special character

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, utf8-decode

my sql query returns no  result when  just the value to return 
have special character. exemple :

the query is :

```
$sql = "SELECT * from categorie ";

    $result = $conn->query(sprintf($sql));
```

the result was in json

```
   {"rows":2,"categorie":[{"idCategorie":"8","nomCategorie":"loisir ","imageCategorie":"imgCategorie1.png"},{"idCategorie":"9","nomCategorie":"destination","imageCategorie":"imgCategorie2.png"}],"message":"Liste cat\u00e9gorie","error":0}
```

But when I change the "nomCategorie" from "loisir" to "quelle loisir avez vous ??

The query dont return any thing or make chane like `nomCategorie =cinéma paris`

it doesn't work. So I've cancel all the space and the special character and it works

Comment: I 'am using php my admin of ovh

Comment: Are you saying, that when you change json in database, then select query do not work? Impossible. Maybe in php you are doing json_decode() and that is what is not working?

Comment: I 'am doing it with a web service ; i write the query and then I 'am doing with 
json_encode and it dosn't work

Comment: so it is not problem with query but with json_encode... try to focus on problem next time. **json_encode require correct utf8 encoding**

Comment: ive tried this `json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` but alwyes same probleme , HOW CAN I FIX IT ?

Comment: I change the response when fetchin the result but same error : header("Content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 
  
  $response["rows"] = $result->num_rows;
  $response["categorie"] = $rows;
  $response["message"] = "Liste catégorie"; 
  }

Comment: I var_dump teh result , it is ok but with json encode it does not work

Comment: Let's see if the data is already Unicode in the table.  Please do `SELECT message, HEX(message) FROM categorie WHERE ...`.

Comment: It ok I 've find the solution , I just add that ligne in my config file : $conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ok I 've find the solution , I just add that ligne in my config file :

```
 $conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Comment: You don't say what your database library is but encoding is normally a connection property; running a query manually is not the best choice because it doesn't let the client know about the proper encoding. Also, shouldn't it it `set names` rather than `set character set`?

Comment: Related [Is “SET CHARACTER SET utf8” necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566602/is-set-character-set-utf8-necessary) and [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. Any time I was trying to get data with special characters it wasn't being returned. Then I found this very comprehensive guide:

https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql

It wasn't really clear in the question what mysql connector you were using but this guide should have what you are looking for. Here is a basic mysql connection:

```
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
  mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
```

Useful also to note was setting your special characters for display in php within the header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Hope that helps!